# Force Epic Games Launcher into Desktop Mode

Tags: epic-games-launcher

Epic Games Launcher is suddenly opening in Mobile Mode instead of Desktop Mode.

[According to Epic](https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/epic-games-store-c5719341124379/launcher-support-c5719357217435/epic-games-launcher-displays-incorrectly-or-appears-blank-a5720229169819#:%7E:text=Epic%20Games%20Launcher%20is%20displaying,Click%20on%20Display%20Settings.), changing my display scaling would work.  While it does in fact "work", my laptop display becomes so small that I can't actually read anything (characters are about 1mm high).

Is there a way (like a command line switch) to force the launcher to display in desktop mode instead of mobile mode?

Comment: If you haven't yet, try [clearing the web cache](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Store:Epic_Games_Store#Issues_fixed). At the default scale, does it eventually change to desktop layout if you make the window wider or is it only mobile mode? If it does change then it is likely using "responsive web design" and there won't be any way around it outside of using [legendary](https://github.com/derrod/legendary). If it does not change then there may be some option to toggle; check [the config files](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Store:Epic_Games_Store#Client_data) and maybe you will get lucky.